# Check authorization with express basic auth only

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to check if someone has entered an authorized username and password in my link for a specific path called `'/protected'` example:
admin:admin@localhost:8080/protected

If the person has inputted this then he will arrive to a page says "welcome authorized"

If the person hasn't inputted the link like this instead just:
localhost:8080/protected
He will receive a message "not authorized" along with error 401

This is the code that i came up with but only if you are authorized will receive a message, else you don't receive anything.

```
router.get('/protected', basicAuth({
        users: {'admin':'admin'}
    }),(req,res)=>{
    res.send('Welcome, authenticated client');
});
```

Comment: You should use middleware for it: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `express-basic-auth` package, which by default sends no response body when authorization is rejected.

[Per the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth#unauthorized-response-body), to add a response body to requests that fail authorization, you need to add the `unauthorizedResponse` property to the object you pass to the `basicAuth` middleware.

To add a generic message, it can be as simple as a string.

```
router.get('/protected', basicAuth({
        users: {'admin':'admin'},
        unauthorizedResponse: 'not authorized'
    }),(req,res)=>{
    res.send('Welcome, authenticated client');
});
```

To add a dynamic message, you can use a function (which will have access to the request object through the first parameter):

```
router.get('/protected', basicAuth({
        users: {'admin':'admin'},
        unauthorizedResponse: getUnauthorizedResponse
    }),(req,res)=>{
    res.send('Welcome, authenticated client');
});

function getUnauthorizedResponse(req) {
    const { user } = req.auth?.user ?? {}
    return user ? `invalid credentials for user '${user}'` : 'no credentials provided';
}
```

Comment: @KahilMa if the answer is correct, please up vote, too. :)